# gdb - re-setting a const

Tags: c++, c, gdb, constants

I have

```
const int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 500;
//...
if(clients.size() < MAX_CONNECTIONS) {
    //...
}
```

I'm trying to find the "right" choice for MAX_CONNECTIONS.  So I fire up gdb and `set MAX_CONNECTIONS = 750`.  But it seems my code isn't responding to this change.  I wonder if it's because the const int was resolved at compile time even though it wound up getting bumped at runtime.  Does this sound right, and, using GDB is there any way I can bypass this effect without having to edit the code in my program?  It takes a while just to warm up to 500.

Comment: have you tried it without const?

Comment: I don't like that for two reasons.  One, trying not to restart my program - want to hot debug.  Two, it really is a const in the spirit of the program...  it's only in kooky debugging nonsense that it makes sense to change it.

Comment: I wouldn't say "use a 'variable' if you want the value to 'vary'" is "kooky debugging nonsense" ;)

Comment: write a small program with a const a and with a non const b; you might see the difference; for your program you could have a #ifndef DEBUG if you want to make the value tunable (not const) when debugging

Comment: const behaves differently in C and C++. You should choose which one you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the compiler, seeing that the variable is `const`, is inlining the constant into the assembly and not having the generated code actually read the value of the `MAX_CONNECTIONS` variable.  The C++ spec is worded in a way where if a variable of primitive type is explicitly marked `const`, the compiler can make certain assumptions about it for the purposes of optimization, since any attempt to change that constant is either (1) illegal or (2) results in undefined behavior.

If you want to use GDB to do things like this, consider marking the variable `volatile` rather than `const` to indicate to the compiler that it shouldn't optimize it.  Alternatively, have this information controlled by some other data source (say, a configuration option inside a file) so that you aren't blasting the program's memory out from underneath it in order to change the value.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

By telling it it's `const`, you're telling the compiler it has freedom to not load the value, but to build it directly into the code when possible. An allocated copy may still exist for those times when the particular instructions chosen need to load a value rather than having an immediate value, or it could be omitted by the compiler as well. That's a bit of a loose answer short on standardese, but that's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

As this post is quite old, my answer is more like a reference to my future self. Assuming you compiled in debug mode, running the following expression in the debugger (lldb in my case) works:

```
const_cast<int&>(MAX_CONNECTIONS) = 750
```

In case you have to change the constant often, e.g. in a loop, set a breakpoint and evaluate the expression each time the breakpoint is hit

```
breakpoint set <location>
breakpoint command add <breakpoint_id>
const_cast<int&>(MAX_CONNECTIONS) = 750
DONE
```